# POST from Form to external API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm quite noob into asp.net

I'm building a simple solution in VS2019, using asp.net MVC, which is supposed to send a User data to another API which will be responsible for saving into database.

So far, both APIs are REST and I'm not using `core`

Basically, it is a form with a submit that will POST to the external project, pretty simple.
I'm following some tutorials and stuff but there are so many different ways that got me confused, so I decided to ask here

Here's what I have so far

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async ActionResult Index(User user)
{

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://pathtoAPI.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    User newuser = new User()
    {
        email = user.email,
        nome = user.nome,
        cpf = user.cpf,
        cnpj = user.cnpj,
        userName = user.userName,
        senha = user.senha,
        telefone = user.telefone
    };            

    var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newuser);
    var contentString = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    contentString.Headers.ContentType = new
    MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    //contentString.Headers.Add("Session-Token", session_token); 

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("register", contentString);
    return Content($"{response}");
}
```

I want to receive the "OK" message from the other API and just print it on my screen, I'm using the `cshtml` file to handle the front and the form as well.

The return though seems to be wrong, it's expecting either 'null, task, task, or something like.

Can someone please help me with this code?

Thanks

Comment: You could use an ajax call in javascript to send the data straight to the API, it seems needless to involve the Controller.

Comment: @0liveradam8 There are legitimate reasons why you'd want to involve the controller. For example, the remote API requires you to connect using SSL certificates, which wouldn't be available to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the content of the response, not the response object itself.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("register", contentString);
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return Content(responseBody);
```

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah but then he'd have to take that stream and write it to his own response stream, so this just seemed easier to explain.

Comment: That's it, I just read the same in the asp.net documentation for async, thanks!